# Cannot start mongod service on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mongodb

I uninstalled mongo using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
```

Then installed it again using following commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
sudo echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

I get the below errors:

```
Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mongod, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-org:
mongodb-org depends on mongodb-org-server; however:
Package mongodb-org-server is not configured yet.
```

How do I fix this? I would like to install a stable version of Mongo.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps that I executed for a successful installation:

```sh
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org*
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=3.2.4 mongodb-org-server=3.2.4 mongodb-org-shell=3.2.4 mongodb-org-mongos=3.2.4 mongodb-org-tools=3.2.4
sudo mkdir /data/db
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data
```

- Edit `/etc/mongod.conf` and change `dbPath` to `/data/db`.
- Edit `/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=
  Documentation=man:mongod(1)
  After=network.target

  [Service]
  Type=forking
  User=mongodb
  Group=mongodb
  RuntimeDirectory=mongod
  PIDFile=/var/run/mongod/mongod.pid
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --pidfilepath /var/run/mongod/mongod.pid --fork
  TimeoutStopSec=5
  KillMode=mixed

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```

Then it should work.

Comment: Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service not found.